# HTML images won't appear when in the same folder?

Tags: html, css

```
article.uk{
background-image: url("GB_Flag.jpg");
background-color: #95a5a6;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
width: 75%;
background-size: contain;
color:#d98880;
}
```

```
<a href="GB.html" target="Great_Britain_Page">
  <article class="uk">
  <h2>British Warplanes of World War II</h2>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  </article>
</a>
```

This is a section of an html file that I am having trouble with, a few days ago the image of a UK flag would appear in the background but now the flag does not appear.  What I think happened was that Windows 10 forced a reboot on my and now the images do not work for any of my files on my thumb drive.  I usually keep my files on the thumb drive and this file was open on Notepad+ when the computer rebooted.  Maybe I'm missing something dumb but all the flags I had on my HTML files quit working at this point.  They are in the same folder as well.

Comment: how are you accessing your webpage? what is the html part that uses your css class?

Comment: Here's the section of my html code that the css goes too I have five exactly the same section just for different countries so I only think I need to share one since they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with where your image is, not with the code. The file `GB_Flag.jpg` needs to be in the same folder as the HTML page this CSS is connected to, otherwise it cannot reach it.

Comment: The CSS is embeded in the HTML document for now and they are in the same folder.  The strange thing is they used to work till now.

Comment: @kwjamesblond The image also needs to be in the same folder. Perhaps it was moved or corrupted? Try opening the image.

Comment: Yeah, the image is in the same folder and I have opened it and it looks fine, I'll try to reinstall notepad+ in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the background-image from the "article" class and directly apply the style to the element

```
style="background-image: url("GB_Flag.jpg");"
```

For example:

```
<div class="article" style="background-image: url("GB_Flag.jpg");"></div>
```

Comment: That does not work either I even tried to reinstall notepad++ but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

apparently Microsoft edge quit showing my images after the windows 10 update, cause I just used firefox to open the html file and the images were there.  Probably just an error on my computer and sorry about the fuss.